# Remove make from cygwin

Tags: cygwin, uninstall, make

I need to work on GNU make 3.80, but cygwin has make 3.81 installed. How can I remove make 3.81 and install 3.80?

I've tried running setup.exe for cygwin and installing make 3.80, it runs fine but in terminal it shows 3.81.

Answer (score 4):

make 3.80 is no longer available from the Cygwin repositories.  But the better question is, **why** do you want such an old version?

Comment: I have an old project which runs on make 3.80 only. I have the package with me, but couldn't install it. I can install 3.82 from cygwin installer, but the package I have is not installing

Comment: I would strongly suggest you fix your package to work with current `make` instead, but in the meantime, you may be able to find this in the [Cygwin Time Machine](http://www.fruitbat.org/Cygwin/#cygwintimemachine).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I've solved it using other method. +1 for the help.

Comment: @Yaakov it seems that the maintainers of GNU Make "broke" it for M$ environments when they moved from 3.80 to 3.81. Some things were "fixed" in a later build, but are broken again in 3.82. Agreed, the best way forward is to fix the projects so as use UNIX-like paths rather than DOS paths, etc. (i.e. what I'm personally working on right this minute) but with build tools the risk is always that you'll need to produce a new build quickly to fix a customer defect, etc.  "Downgrading" Make is often a necessary solution when time is of the essence, sadly :-(

Comment: Now I understand.  We stopped supporting DOS paths with make because the maintenance burden was too heavy and the results too fragile.  Cygwin is a *NIX environment and therefore only *NIX-style paths are guaranteed to work.  You'll be better off fixing your Makefiles and using an officially supported make than trying to hang on to obsolete behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I had devkitpro installed on my pc, which was using make 3.81 version. I found it out by using `which` command.

```
$which make
```

So I uninstalled devkit and reinstalled the recent make package which is 3.82 and then just replaced the `make.exe` from the package I have (3.80) to the `cygwin` bin folder. The method was suggested by the package supplier.
And now the make is working fine and is compatible with my project.